# How to import tiff files and generate contours in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, autocad, civil3d

Very new to GIS, Just learning QGIS from product manuals and online resources. I have 2 .tif files of a regional municipality. I have another 3-4 files ( AutoCAD) which are survey files. I have another file (AutoCAD) utility info file. I would like to create a base file for other consultants to work on from these files. There are projection information only on the survey files.

Not sure if all this can be accomplished with QGIS?

Comment: Yes,you can do it using QGIS. Go ahead, read the documentation, tutorials, etc.

Comment: Definitely, I will do a review.